# Can't bind to 'images' since it isn't a known property of 'angular-image-slider'

Tags: angular

I want to display some images as a slide show and to make it happen I have installed required package but when I execute it its give me below an error Can't bind to 'images' since it isn't a known property of 'angular-image-slider'.
I'm  using Angular 4

I have installed an image slider package and have import in app.module,
I have imported this module in app.module

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SliderModule } from 'angular-image-slider';

imports: [
FormsModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
SliderModule,]
```

I want to run that all images as a slide show, How can I make it happen.
What I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: try restarting the application

Comment: Can you post your code on stackblitz?

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: sure, I can show you html

Comment: <angular-image-slider [images]="imagesUrl"></angular-image-slider>

Comment: did you understand that what I am want to achieve.

Comment: In which module you have imported "SliderModule" ??

Comment: I have impoted it in app.module

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ahsb7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Are you there ?

Comment: I have created stackblitz  but it working fine overthere but I don't know why it not woking in my app

Comment: It works https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vk1sez You need to install angular-image-slider using package manager

Comment: You have added module in app.module but you haven't istalled package in your project...First do "npm install angular-image-slider --save" and the import in app.module

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ahsb7

Comment: I have installed it also

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yegzxj?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: See this in your example you not imported in app.module...Above link is your

Comment: No, I have imported it but still facing the same error

Comment: When I installed this package after this it show me this info
added 46 packages from 94 contributors, removed 21 packages, updated 15 packages and moved 2 packages in 88.654s
fixed 21 of 119 vulnerabilities in 9214 scanned packages
  3 package updates for 98 vulns involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)

Comment: should I  give this below commond to fix issue 
npm audit fix --force

Comment: I found the resolution myself  because I did not import both module where my component was import, I have two module file but I  was adding it in app.module but i had to add it different module then did it and got the solution.